# Linq expression with eager loading only top n records

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-expressions

I am using entity framework core. I am eager loading a navigation property for an entity. What I want to achieve here is only load top 5 records ordered by creation date along with the main entity. I have following query.

```
Context.Foo.Where(f => f.Id == fid)
    .Include(f1 => f1.Bars.OrderByDescending(b => b.CreateDate).Take(LIMIT))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

It throws error that property expression is not valid. I understood that the expression should just evaluate to a property we want to include, but is there a way where we can fine tune the selection of properties?

Comment: Just do manual joins.

Comment: As per the accepted answer on "How to filter “Include” entities in entity framework?" It is currently not supported by EF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filtering includes is not allowed in EF Core to the best on my knowledge.  It does look like there is a github project that adds this feature which may work in your case. https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/wiki/EF-Query-IncludeFilter-%7C-Entity-Framework-Include-Related-Entities-using-Where-Filter

Comment: Even though this is not what I am looking for, at the moment EF do not support the feature, so accepting this answer as its most suitable for now